# Regex match not always present elements

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I have these inputs:

+36919:60546a74:0|POST /api/v1/transactions

-36919:60546a74:0

I am looking for a regex (or a grok pattern) to give me these outputs:

For the first line:

```
in_out: +
id: 36919:60546a74:0
method: POST
url: /api/v1/transactions
```

For the second line:

```
in_out: -
id: 36919:60546a74:0
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

I tried this pattern:

```
IN_OUT [+-]{1}
FORENSIC_ID .*?(?=\|?)
CUSTOM %{IN_OUT:in_out}%{FORENSIC_ID:forensic_id}\|%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request}
```

It gives me good result for the first line, but not for the second because there is no "|" after the ID.

Comment: So, what was the pattern you tried? BTW, `-36919:60546a74` has no `:0` at the end, you can't match what is not present in the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited the post, it was a typo sorry

Comment: What if you just use `^(?<in_out>[-+])(?<id>[\w:]+)(?:\|(?<method>[A-Z]+)\s+(?<url>/.*))?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```rb
^(?<in_out>[-+])(?<id>[\w:]+)(?:\|(?<method>[A-Z]+)\s+(?<url>/.*))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sj5AFj/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<in_out>[-+])` - Group "in_out": a `-` or `+` char
- `(?<id>[\w:]+)` - Group "id": one or more word or `:` chars
- `(?:\|(?<method>[A-Z]+)\s+(?<url>/.*))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\|` - a `|` char
  - `(?<method>[A-Z]+)` - Group "method": one or more uppercase ASCII letters
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?<url>/.*)` - Group "url": a `/` and then any zero or more chars to the end of line

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. Thanks a lot!

In grok syntax:

```
IN_OUT [+-]
FORENSIC_ID [\w:]+
OPTIONAL [\|]?%{WORD:method}\s%{URIPATHPARAM:request}
CUSTOM %{IN_OUT:in_out}%{FORENSIC_ID:forensic_id}%{OPTIONAL:rest}*
```